# SQL Order By Column From another Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
$sql = "SELECT user2 FROM subscriptions WHERE user1 = '$username'";
```

This code works perfectly, but what I would like to do is ORDER it BY a column from my users table, the user_id column. Now I can't do this…

```
$sql = "SELECT user2 FROM subscriptions WHERE user1 = '$username' ORDER BY user_id";
```

Because there is no column called user_id in my subscriptions table, just in my users table.

Comment: what are the indexes??use join.

Comment: Why tag both MySQL and MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: why can't you have extra column in this case? (unless for security purposes)

Comment: @OP: How are the  `'suvscriptions'` and `'users'` tables are connected? What is the `'join'` relation?

Comment: Show your tbl structure

Comment: @sgt user1 and user2 are indexes on the subscriptions table,

Comment: @sgt and id and user_id is the index on the users table

Comment: i would like to get the user_id from user2 where user2 is equal to username in my users table @Ravinder

Comment: @JohnAlvarez: You better post results of `'show create table subscriptions;'` and `'show create table users;'`

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand why you have two `user` columns, maybe it's a typo. But you need to [JOIN](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php) the tables. In this case I've used a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which will only return records from `subscriptions` and what matches the `JOIN` condition from `users`. i.e. `user2 = user_id`.

```
SELECT subscriptions.user2 
FROM subscriptions 
LEFT JOIN users ON subscriptions.user2 = users.username
WHERE subscriptions.user1 = '$username' 
ORDER BY users.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the user_id in your ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT user2 
FROM subscriptions 
WHERE user1 = '$username' 
ORDER BY (select user_id from users where users.username = subscriptions.user2);
```

I surmise that users.username is unique, so you have two natural unique keys in your users table (user_id and username). You've decided to use username for references in other tables. That is okay.

If, however, users.username is not unique, then your databse design is broken and you should use the user_id as reference in other tables instead of username, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`JOIN` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) and after you can order by `user_id` from the `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular join (not LEFT JOIN) if you have one-to-one data relation.

```
SELECT a.user2 FROM subscriptions a, user b 
WHERE a.user2 = b.username
AND a.usera.user1 = '$username' ORDER BY b.user_id
```

This is hard to give working solution without viewing table's scheme. But from the query it's looks like you have poor dab design if you use '$username' to search in subscriptions instead of users table.

With an good database design your query should be like this:

```
SELECT a.fiel1, a.field2, a.user_id, b.field1, b.field2, b.user_id 
    FROM subscriptions a, user b 
    WHERE a.user_id = b.user_id
    AND b.username = '$username' ORDER BY b.user_id
```

- Joins by user_id
- Storing username once in users table
- Use user_id in any other tables

Comment: thank you, and I only named the variable that so it would be easier for the readers to know what I was doing instead of random letters

Answer (score -2):

u should use `order by user_id desc`